# How to write proofs using set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I want to learn how to write proofs. I have read about different proof techniques, like direct proofs and contradiction, etc. But I can't seem to get past basic examples.

I have seen how naive set theory and ZFC is the standard for writing proofs now.

But I have no idea how to write, say, a direct proof using set theory.

I read [this page](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ealoveles/Math300Summer2011/ExamplesOfProofs.pdf) and the first example uses set builder notation to create sets (that consist of algebra), that then use set theory to write the proof. Is this how you write proofs with set theory? Or am I missing something? How do I incorporate algebraic expressions into the proofs while also using sets.

Basically, I am asking for help on how to write proofs, like a direct proof, using set theory.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE. The methods in the pdf you linked are rather standard, if most students were to prove those same things, they would probably prove them in more or less the same way (having seen similar proofs enough times, the answer just sort of jumps out, but this takes some practice). For example, if you want to prove that two sets are equal, you show they are subsets of each other often times (this is not always how it is done, there are other ways depending on the context, sometimes $A\subseteq B$ and there is some property A has, which guarantees A to be all of B, but for very basic set theory, often times yes that is how it's done), like they did in that pdf you linked. And yes, for that first example, the way they proved that is really the standard way you would prove this fact. Now as you get farther in mathematics, you have more tools at your disposal (like say: topology, abstract algebra, and real analysis) so the proofs get more complicated, but the methods you see in this pdf are very standard and I would make sure you understand the proofs. There are some very good books on introductory set theory I would suggest reading. "A TeXas Style Introduction to Proof" for example. To build these skills it is really up to you to just practice basic proofs, that's not really something someone else can do for you (for the most part). If you post a solution to a problem on MSE and ask for verification, we can also check your proof, and comment on it (/make sure it's correct).

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I have been studying various areas of math now for a few months, and proof writing is the area I have the most trouble with. But practice makes perfect, so I will continue trying to see how far I get in my understanding.

Comment: My biggest problem currently is how to incorporate algebraic expressions into the proofs while also using sets.